# I'm trying to test a variable of a ping value, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: macos, variables, terminal, ping

```
    ping_average=(ping -c 10 na.leagueoflegends.com | tail -1|awk'{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2)
    [ “ping_average” < “176” ] && echo “Play” || echo “No”
```

This value seems to not be working, and I get the error code "Unexpected token near '/" and 176: No such file or directory."

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems here...

- You need a `$` for both variable expansion (so use `$ping_average` instead of just `ping_average`) and command substitution (so use `$(ping ...)`instead of just `(ping ...)`).
- You need a space between `awk` and its argument. In the shell, spaces are important syntax; you can't just add or remove them in most places.
- bash doesn't do floating-point arithmetic (even just comparisons), so you need to look at just the integer part of the ping result. You could do this by adding `| cut -d . -f 1` to the ping pipeline.
- The second line is full of fancy ("smart") double-quotes, which the shell will treat as normal characters and get confused by. Use an editor that doesn't "helpfully" convert plain quotes to the fancy versions.
- The `<` is being treated as an input redirect (i.e. read from the file named "176") -- you'd either need to use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]`, or quote/escape it. But don't do that because...
- In a test expression, `<` does string comparison instead of numeric comparison. For example, `[ 9 '<' 176 ]` would be false because "9" comes after "1" in sorting order. Instead, `-lt` (as in `[ 9 -lt 176 ]`).

So, with all that corrected, I get:

```
ping_average=$(ping -c 10 na.leagueoflegends.com | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d '/' -f 2 | cut -d . -f 1)
[ "$ping_average" -lt "176" ] && echo "Play" || echo "No"
```

BTW, I recommend running your code through [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net); it won't spot all possible problems, but it'll point out many common mistakes. In this case, though, it would've been too confused by the `ping_average=(ping ...) expression to tell you much.